# Firebase data structure query

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

After reading the documentation they recommend not using nested data structure. I am thinking this is the best way for my data but I am not sure how to add the tripId to the hotels collection.

My other option is having the user enter the "BOL" for each hotel entry... My problem with that method is how do I query the date to see all the hotels that match the "trip"?

EDIT::::::::
What I am trying to accomplish is when a user selects a trip it runs a query and displays the total of all the nights in a hotel associated with that trip.

```
users:
    - gCFiwSLwBeg87N6GfeofFxIAZyi2
        - UID: gCFiwSLwBeg87N6GfeofFxIAZyi2
        - firstName: "James"
        - email: "a@email.com"

trips:
    - "random document id"
        - bol: "1234567"
        - startDate: "1/3/2022"
        - destination: "Sacramento, CA"
        - userID: "Users UID"
        - foodTotal: "100"
        - hotelTotal: "240"
    - "random document id"
        - bol: "256976"
        - startDate: "2/5/2022"
        - destination: "Orlando, FL"
        - userID: "Users UID"
        - foodTotal: "150"
        - hotelTotal: "400"

hotels:
    - "random document id"
        - tripId: ?
        - date: "1/4/2022"
        - destination: "Sacramento, CA"
        - userID: "Users UID"
        - name: "Hotel Inn"
        - cost: "120"
    - "random document id"
        - tripId: ?
        - date: "1/5/2022"
        - destination: "Sacramento, CA"
        - userID: "Users UID"
        - name: "Hotel Inn"
        - cost: "120"
```

Here is the function I am currently using to add Hotels to firebase.

```
class FirebaseHotelRepository: HotelRepositoryProtocol {
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()

func addHotel(hotel: Hotel, completion: @escaping (Result<Hotel?, Error>) -> Void) {
        do {
            var addedHotel = hotel
            addedHotel.userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let _ = try db.collection("hotels").addDocument(from: addedHotel)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to encode trip: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

class AddHotelViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let repo: HotelRepositoryProtocol

    var name: String = ""
    var location: String = ""
    var date = Date()
    var cost: String = ""

    @Published var saved: Bool = false
    
    init(repo: HotelRepositoryProtocol) {
        self.repo = repo
    }
    
    func addHotel() {
        let hotel = Hotel(bol: bol,
                          name: name,
                          location: location,
                          date: date,
                          cost: cost,
                          color: UIColor(color).hexStringFromColor())
        
        repo.addHotel(hotel: hotel) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let savedHotel):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.saved = savedHotel == nil ? false : true
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with SwiftUI, which is a framework for displaying UI. Perhaps you're looking for an answer in Swift, which is the underlying language behind SwiftUI?

Comment: What is wrong with adding "tripId to the hotels collection"?

Comment: Hi @OEZ ,  your 1st options seems doable, on your 1st option, you can add the document ID of the `trips` collection to `hotels` collection just by getting the document ID after creation and create another query to create a document for hotels which then you include the document ID from the created `trips` document.

Comment: Have you tried any? If so, please include it on your question.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I have tried several things including using a completely different course example that didn't use Repositories. I am not even sure the Repository approach is what I need but it has been the one I was able to get to work until this point.

Comment: I don't know if this will help to not... what I am trying to do is with each trip the user will be keeping track of hotel, food, and any misc expense receipts. I am trying to make it so that when the user looks at the trip details they can see they total cost of each category under expenses.

Comment: @AlexMamo nothing is wrong with I just don't know how to do that and haven't been able to find any examples of it.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Are you saying that a user knows the date of a trip and they want to query for all hotels with a matching date? From that you would then know the cost of each hotel for that date? If that's not it, can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay I am trying to set it up so when the user goes to the view the details of a trip it will have already calculated the total cost of the hotels for that trip. I also plan on doing the samething for food and misc expenses.

Comment: When the user selects a trip, query the associated hotels and add up the total and present it to the user, right? I would advise against storing the hotel total in the trip itself as hotel rates change frequently - a query of those hotels would produce an accurate total at that moment. So what's the trouble?  What code are you having difficulty with? Can you update the question so we know what to assist with?

Comment: @Jay you hit it right on with what I am wanting to do... I was just thinking I needed the tripId saved with the hotels in order to do that query. To answer your question I don't know how to query the hotels to display the total for the nights associated with the trip.

Comment: Should I change the title and wording of this post or just create a new one that asks the question properly?

Comment: Nope - you're good and I added an answer with several options. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let start with clarifying this

> not using nested data structure

Everything in Firebase is nested! - that's the way it works. That's in reference to DEEPLY nesting data as it makes it hard to get to/query etc so denormalizing or flattening the data is an often used practice.

There are a number of ways to get the data you want but let me re-state the question

> I have trips and each trip has a number of associated hotels. My goal
> is to read the hotels for each trip to calculate a total cost for
> those hotels.

TL;DR Skip to the bottom: One Quick Thing section

Here's one structure

```
trip_0
   trip_name: "Napa trip"
   hotels:
     hotel_0: true
     hotel_1: true
     hotel_2: true
```

with that structure, reading in trip_0 will provide the associated hotels. You then then iterate over that array (map) and read in hotel_0 and get it's  cost, then hotel_1 and get it's cost. Add the costs up and you're done. No query required.

A second option is a reverse approach with a seperate collection that links hotels and trips - this requires a query to get the hotels associated with each trip

```
hotels_trips
   hotel_0
      trip_0: true
      trip_1: true
      trip_2: true
   hotel_1
      trip_1: true
```

with the above, run a query on the hotels_trips collection for hotels there trip_1 is true. Once you have the list of hotels you can read each one to get it's cost and add them up.

Another solution is a structure and a query using arrayContains:

```
hotels
   hotel_0
      hotel_name: "Hotel California"
      cost: 500
      trip_array
         0: trip_0
         1: trip_1
```

and then the code that will query the hotels collection for all hotels that contains trip_0

```
func queryHotels() {
    let hotelCollection = self.db.collection("hotels")
    hotelCollection.whereField("trip_array", arrayContains: "trip_0").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            let name = doc.get("name") as! String
            print(name)
        }
    }
}
```

**One quick thing**: Arrays are typically challenging to work with in NoSQL databases like Firebase so I usually avoid them. You may want to consider using a Map instead of an array and then query on the path `trip_map/trip_0` to see if it's true. The hotels structure would include this instead of the trip_array

```
trip_map
   trip_0: true
   trip_1: true
```

and the query would test the path to see if it's value is true

```
hotelCollection.whereField("trip_map.trip_0", isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call doc():

Here's a sample code that you can refer to:

```
let trips = db.collection("trips").addDocument(data: [
 // trips' data
])

// This will append tripId to the `addedHotel`
addedHotel["tripId"] = trips.documentID

let hotels = db.collection("hotels").addDocument(from: addedHotel)
```

The above code should get the document ID of the trips' and you can manually append or construct the data that you should pass to the hotels` document.

---

You can find more relevant information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference).

Comment: I have read the documentation and it appears to be what I need..... unfortunately I have no clue where to put this in my code.